# how to set static text transparent in mfc

Tags: c++, mfc, activex, transparent, static-text

I am developing a  ActiveX controls. which looks like an edit box with some extra added functionality.
There is an label which is nothing but the static text.
I am creating the static text as following,

```
m_hWnd = (HWND)CreateWindowExW(0, WC_STATICW, L"", dwStyle, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, m_Parent->m_hWnd, 0, 0, 0);
```

But the issue is the background color of the static text which is coming as white.
I tried setting BkMode on the method onCtrlColor but nothing is working out.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/73999/

Comment: @himanshu I have added the following code in OnCtlColor method `SetBkMode(pDC->m_hDC, TRANSPARENT); return (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(COLOR_BACKGROUND);` still it is not working.

Comment: Try to have a class member transparent brush and return it on the OnCtlColor  method. By the way did you confirm the execution flow passes on the OnCtlColor method?

Comment: @AnoopKumar, try returning `return (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);`

Comment: @Himanshu still it is not working.

Comment: @sergiol yes execution flow I have checked. I tried making an transparent brush as member variable and returning from OnCtlColor but it did not worked